# DIV onClick event force download a pdf file

Tags: php, javascript, html, onclick

I want to make a DIV onclick which will open a dialog box to save a pdf file.

Something like this (html5 a href):

```
<a href="path" download>download</a>
```

but using onclick event on DIV.

i tried but it's not working:

```
<div onClick="window.location='path' download">something</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<div onClick="window.location=location/to/file/pdf.php">something</div>
```

pdf.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('path/to/your_file.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div onClick="window.location='path'; return false;">something</div>
```

You should set correct headers on server side which will determine view or download a file

Comment: its not working ;/ pdf is still being displayed and no prompt to download is shown. where to put these headers ? in my main index.php file ?

Answer (score 0):

The header sections of this kind of apps must be taking seriously if you want the to work, if you do not have those show by Michał Prajsnar, i say go back and put them in and try again.

You can just google that same thing and solutions on the fly.

try these :

http://www.amember.com/forum/threads/force-file-downloads-with-htaccess.14980/

http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Comment: question was targeted to div onclick event (not force download only). I was wondering if there is any way to do this without external file i.e. pdf.php. but nevertheless thank you :-]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div onClick="window.open('path', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes'); return false;">something</div>
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Anyone has cons and pros for this approach?