# How To make it so when you click an html button, it downloads a file to the persons computer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, download

```
<button type="submit" class="myButton" onclick="window.open('test.txt')">Money Dispenser</button>
```

Is the current code i have, and does not do anything at all when i click it. ( I want it to download test.txt to the computer or device of the user who cliked it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DIV onClick event force download a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505692/div-onclick-event-force-download-a-pdf-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve using a submit button, if it's not mandatory I'd use an `<a>`.

### With pure HTML5 using the `download` attribute

```html
<a href="test.txt" download>Money Dispenser</a>
```

### Or with Javascript if you *have* to use a `<button>`

This has already been covered grealy [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file)

But the gist of it is, create a function to download files as shown on that thread and add it to your `<button>`

```html
<button onclick="donwloaURI('data:text/plain,Test', 'Test.txt')">Money Dispenser</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using:

```
<a href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,test.txt" download>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML `download` attribute to specify that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.

```
<a href="/download-file-path-here" download>
  Money Dispenser
</a>
```